# How to look for special/escape characters in XPATH 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube, xpath-1.0

I am working with an open source code review tool named SonarQube. This application allows specific programming constraints to be tailored to how you want these rules to be applied and reviewed to either fail or pass.

I am working on a code review for formatting and looking for errors/bugs/vulnerabilities in XML paths. I am having trouble trying to catch special characters in these paths

For Example this XPATH 1.0 expression works on finding 'http' in the location attribute

```
//definitions/service/port/address[contains(@location,'http')]
```

This expression will return true because it finds *http*. However,

```
//definitions/service/port/address[contains(@location,'http:')]
```

This expression does not return true because I believe the character **:** is causing something to be misinterpreted.

Below is some example code I do my tests on. Is there some work around for this or special characters to be used in a situation like this?

```
<definitions>
    <service >
       <port>
          <address location="http://example.com"/>
        </port>
     </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about a `:` character in a string literal in XPath.

Both XPath expressions will return the `address` element shown in your XML document.  If SonarQube behaves different than this (possible but unlikely), then it would appear to be an issue with SonarQube.

You may have inadvertently reduced significant aspects of the actual problem while attempting to provide a minimal MCVE.

Comment: That's what I thought but it simply wasn't working. Still new to learning XPATH. It very well could be an issue with SonarQube so I will need to look into it. Will mark this as answered. If I find a solution I'll answer it on here. Thanks @kjughes